# MySQLi query to Array - Looping over array returns empty results

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

So, this is an odd thing I have encountered and maybe it’s because of the late night or I am just missing something basic here. I have to send the query to array instead of looping over the query because other API calls can send the array instead of coming from the DB. The query returns multiple items as it’s supposed too. On to the code:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT ID FROM tblTemp WHERE FOREIGN_KEY='2'");
$tmp = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);        

for($i = count($tmp); $i > 0; --$i) {
echo '<option value="'.$tmp[$i-1].'">Item '.$i.'</option>';
}
```

So, I am simply trying to get the array items into a HTML select. This works fine for passed $tmp arrays; however, what happens when you use the query is, that only the first record is populated in the select. The correct amount of items is added, but the values are missing.
i.e.

```
<option value="">Item 2</option>
<option value="7">Item 1</option>
```

EDIT: PHP does throw an error of: Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only fetching one record from query, that's why you have one value and get an Undefined offset.
In the following example a while loop is used to fetch all the results from the query.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT ID FROM tblTemp WHERE FOREIGN_KEY='2'");
$html = "";
$i = 1;
while($tmp = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $html = '<option value="'.$tmp['ID'].'">Item '.$i.'</option>'.html;
    $i++;
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that; however, the code as it stands shows 2 items in the $tmp array.  This is visible as 2 elements are added during the for loop.  I cannot change the for loop as it might be a query or it might be a passed array, so by default everything goes to array.  Should I just hack this and while loop through the query and add the items to the $tmp array?  I just figure there is a cleaner method.

Comment: @user1666691 You get two items in the array because you pass `MYSQLI_BOTH` in `fetch_array` one has an id of `0` and the other an id on `ID` but its the same value. If you need an array, as you say just build one in the while loop from the query result.

Comment: Right-o.  After messing with this, I figured this is what I would end up having to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

```
 
  for($i = count($tmp); $i > 0; --$i) {
    echo 'Item '.$i.'';
  }
```

should work if **$tmp** returned the right amount. Ensure that **$tmp** returned the proper data.

 
Hope this helps.

Comment: When I did that passed arrays no longer function.  They show up one short.

Comment: Are you certain **$tmp** returned the proper data from the database? That should work.

Comment: The proper data was returned, but apparently fetch_array does not get all results into an array that you can just reference.  It simply gets the point to the record in the resultset and you loop through the pointers.  The above answer solved the issue by looping through and pushing the values to the $tmp array.